# android javascript interface doesn't react

Tags: javascript, android, interface

I've been developing a small app that should make a call over javascript in a web view and js should call back a java method. My aim is to have

------------- result

printed, but I never see it! My code is as simple as this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView wv;

    private Object obj = new Object() {
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void onLogin() {
            System.out.println("------------- result ");
        }
    };

    private String jsString = "var checkLogin = function() {" +
            "window.AndroidJSBridge.onLogin();" + 
        "}; " + 
        "checkLogin();";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        System.out.println("------------- start");

        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.login_webview);
        wv.addJavascriptInterface(obj, "AndroidJSBridge");
        wv.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.loadData("", "text/html", null);
        wv.loadUrl("javascript: " + jsString);
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't use `System.out`, instead, use the Android logcat like so `Log.i("AppName", "------------- result ");`

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to make sure the webview has finished loading the page before you make calls to it:

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
     public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl("javascript: " + jsString);
        }
    });
```

Secondly, you shouldn't need "window." to call the javascript interface (haven't tested this but my code doesn't require that it is there):

```
private String jsString = "var checkLogin = function() {" +
        "AndroidJSBridge.onLogin();" + 
    "}; " + 
    "checkLogin();";
```

Let me know if that works for ya.